# Prove that EXIST = {$<M>$:There exists a string $w ∈ Σ*$ such that $M$ halts on $w$} is undecidable

Tags: computability, reductions, halting-problem

This is a question by my professor Z. Luria in my Computability course.

My first approach was to try and prove it by contradiction, assuming that EXIST is decidable and using the algorithm that decides EXIST to decide HALT which leads to contradiction - but I didn't managed to do so.

Then I tried to prove by Reduction from HALT to EXIST but I fail to define the reduction function.

My main issue with both approaches is that the two Machines receives two different things (and not for example two machines or a machine and a word $w$)

It seems like a rather easy reduction/proof by I'm new to this subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a Turing machine $T$ and a input word $x$, you can compute the description of a Turing machine $M_T^x$ that ignores its input, rewrites the tape to contain $x$, and then simulates $T$.

Now, either $M_T^x$ halts for all input words $w$, or it doesn't halt for any.
Moreover, $M_T^x$ halts if and only if $T$ halts with input $x$, i.e.,  $M_T^x \in \mathsf{EXIST} \iff \langle T, x\rangle \in \mathsf{HALT}$.

Since $\mathsf{HALT}$ is indecidable, so is $\mathsf{EXIST}$.

Comment: I'll try to understand it, but just to make sure - shouldn't the input word of $T$ be $w$?

Comment: @RedYoel. I just fixed a typo, so that's probably why you were confused (sorry!). I'm using $x$ for the input of $T$, and $w$ for the input of $M_T^x$.